# Conversion of string to long long integer using strtoll when char exceeds

Tags: c, string.h

I am converting string to long long integer using strtoll function.
when input string is 63 char I am not getting any problem.

But when it exceeds 63 character giving me wrong result.

```
char *pEnd1;
long long ll_i1 = 0;
ll_i1 = strtoll (newDE1, &pEnd1, 2);
```

works ==> newDE1 = "11111011011101101................" 63 character.
Not working ==> newDE1 = "11111011011101101................" 64 characters.
Is there is any inbuilt function to implement.

Comment: Provide **all** required information. There are no builtin functions in C.

Comment: check your array size of newDE1

Answer (score 1):

Per the [`strtoll` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html):

> The strtol() function returns the result of the conversion, unless the
>   value would underflow or overflow.  If an underflow occurs, strtol()
>   returns LONG_MIN.  **If an overflow occurs, strtol() returns LONG_MAX. 
>   In both cases, errno is set to ERANGE.**  Precisely the same holds for
>   strtoll() (with LLONG_MIN and LLONG_MAX instead of LONG_MIN and
>   LONG_MAX).

Given that you've posted your trying to convert a string of more than 63 characters, you're likely getting an overflow.

Comment: Yes I am getting overflow.

Comment: @user2357643 So your problem then is that you should not be passing strings to `strtoll` that would overflow or underflow the `long long int` data type.

Comment: Is there is any way to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`stroll()` will set the correct errno (ERANGE) and provide either `llong_min` if the value would underflow, or `llong_max` if it would overflow, which is exactly what you are causing by passing more then 63 characters.

Answer (score 0):

OP's `long long` can not represent the 64-`char` string as a positive integer as the value overflows `LLONG_MAX`.

For values in the `unsigned long long` range use:

```
// long long ll_i1 = 0;
// ll_i1 = strtoull (newDE1, &pEnd1, 2);
unsigned long long ull_i1;
ull_i1 = strtoull (newDE1, &pEnd1, 2);
```